# Using indexOf() in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this `[HT2787UK: "9618", HT2787Z1UK: "9619", HT2787Z3UK: "9621", HT2787Z2UK: "9620"]`. I got this from console.

I trying to find out value like below

```
var sku = skus_colorcode.indexOf('9620');                   
console.log(sku);
```

But it is returning -1.

Why I am getting this result ??

Comment: `.indexOf` looks only at numeric indices. Your Array has been populated with non-numeric properties, which will be ignored. So the question would be why an Array is being used this way in the first place.

Comment: That's not an array...

Comment: This is invalid array syntax. If you modify it to an object, you can use ES6 methods to get the key: `Object.entries(skus_colorcode).find(a => a[1] == "9620")[0]`.

Comment: I think the OP made it sufficiently clear that the syntax shown is the output from a console, which isn't required to represent data as valid JS syntax.

Comment: I think this must be an object not an array!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code is not valid at all. An array is a list of elements, without keys.
You must use an object, like this :

```
var skus_colorcode = {HT2787UK: "9618", HT2787Z1UK: "9619", HT2787Z3UK: "9621", HT2787Z2UK: "9620"}
```

To find the key (HT....) that corresponds to "9620", try this code :

```
var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(skus_colorcode), key;

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    if(skus_colorcode[keys[i]] === "9620") {
        key = keys[i];
        break;
    }

// The right key is into the "key" variable
console.log(key); // says "HT2787Z2UK"
```

Comment: An array can hold non-numeric keys and be perfectly valid. The syntax shown wouldn't be a valid initializer, but that's clearly not the actual syntax the OP used to construct the array.

Comment: On my browser (latest version of Chrome) the array cause a syntax error

Comment: *"...The syntax shown wouldn't be a valid initializer, but that's clearly not the actual syntax the OP used to construct the array"*

Comment: `var a = []; a.foo = "bar"; console.log(a.foo); // bar`

Comment: Yes, that syntax works, but not the array given in the question : [HT2787UK: "9618", HT2787Z1UK: "9619", HT2787Z3UK: "9621", HT2787Z2UK: "9620"]
And an array is made to accept only numerical indexes, for other indexes you have to use an object.

Comment: Again, you *can* use an array to hold non-numeric indices. This is because an Array *is* an Object. `[] instanceof Object; // true`. And again, the OP is ***not** showing the syntax he used to create the array*; the OP is showing output from a console, as stated in the question. If it was actual syntax, the whole script would fail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function arraySearch(arr,val) {
    for (var key in arr) {
        this_val = array[key];
        if(this_val == val){
            return key;
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your code has a big problem : Using a for(var ...) loop is VERY slow. You should use `Object.keys(arr);` and next do an incremental loop like I did to  search through the array.

Comment: @ClementNerma: How do you think `Object.keys` is able to collect the keys? `Object.keys` also has to perform a `.hasOwnProperty()` check on each key. Did you actually test the performance?

Comment: Yes I've tested the performances. Object.keys() does not perform a .hasOwnProperty() because it's a C++ native function. So execution is faster than a JavaScript code. Strangely, for(var i in ...) is one of the slower way to explore an object.


NOTE : I did an error that's not Object.keys() but Object.getOwnPropertyNames().

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
   var obj = {HT2787UK: "9618", HT2787Z1UK: "9619", HT2787Z3UK: "9621", HT2787Z2UK: "9620"}

for (var key of obj) {
  if (obj[key] == "9620"){
     return key;
  }
}

return false
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with "hemnath mouli" code should be like as he wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    keys = {HT2787UK: "9618", HT2787Z1UK: "9619", HT2787Z3UK: "9621", HT2787Z2UK: "9620"};
    function getIndexOf(obj,value){
        var count = 0;
        for (var i in obj){
            if(obj[i] == value.toString()){
                return  "index[" + count + "]:" + obj[i]  + " = " + i;
                //return what you want
            }
            count ++;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then U got the values

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(getIndexOf(keys,9621));
</script>
```

Could you please send a piece of code to retrieve the values @ClementNerma even I agree with you this is not the more efficient way.

I just do not want to "downvote" the question.

Or if you want to convert your Object to an Array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    keys = {HT2787UK: "9618", HT2787Z1UK: "9619", HT2787Z3UK: "9621", HT2787Z2UK: "9620"};
    function obj2Array(obj){
        k = [];
        for (var i in obj){
            k.push(obj[i]);
        }
        return k;
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    arr = obj2Array(keys);
    alert (arr[2]);
</script>
```

@abu abu

Answer (score -2):

You can use Jquery:

```
var skus_colorcode = {HT2787UK: "9618", HT2787Z1UK: "9619", HT2787Z3UK: "9621", HT2787Z2UK: "9620"}


$.each( skus_colorcode , function( key, value ) {
   if(value == '9620')
       alert(key);
});
```